# Connecting Popover View to iPad's Detail View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have UISplitViewController that I want to be updated from a UIViewController that is housed in a UIPopoverController.

When I select a cell in the master VC (the left table in a split view) connected with the detail VC, I use this:

```
DetailViewControlleriPad *dvc = [[self.splitViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
dvc.detailItem = object;
```

However, I tried doing this in the popover, but it doesn't update the detail view.  Is there a way to make this work, or can I only update the detail view from the master view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to call:

```
[dvc.view setNeedDisplay];
```

Comment: It says dvc does not respond to that method

Answer (score 0):

You should implement [UISplitViewControllerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios//ipad/#/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and use its methods to get a reference to the root view controller and detail view controller.

Another method would be to always have a reference to your detailviewcontroller in the root view controller (from the beginning in IB or through code) instead of trying to find it in the splitviewcontroller's view hierarchy.

Comment: My uiviewcontroller is all setup and that kink does not help. That is purely related to the master and detail view interacting with each other. My popover that I wnt to update the detail view is not a part of the uisplitview